# AJAX code not running

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, http

I review this code for many time but I don't know where it is problem :
http://pastebin.com/G9hKn7BU

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        function load(){
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else{
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ){
                        document.getElementById('adiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }

        }
        xmlhttp.open('GET','inculde.inc.php',true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="submit" onclick = "load();">
        <div id ="adiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I run it in any browser but nothing happen .

Comment: Provide for information!

Comment: What does your web server should return? And you did not declare your variable with the 'var' keyword

Comment: include.inc.php just simple echo in php

Comment: What do you have in your "inculde.inc.php"? and did you check for errors in console? Maybe function could not even find the php file!

Comment: You could add the error messages or a brief description of the result (example: empty page), to make the problem easier to trace.

Comment: Thanks for all of you , problem solved . just use totoro way .